# Tweepy 3.5 - error in streaming.py: line = buf.read_line().strip()

Tags: python, tweepy

This error occurs intermittently when parsing Twitter data using streaming.py in Tweepy 3.5. 
I have seen discussions about this in past postings, but have yet to see a solution. 
One person suggested installing Tweepy 3.2, but we are on 3.5 now, so this does not seem reasonable.

The trace and my software versions are listed below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "newt5.py", line 223, in <module>
    sapi.filter(track=['BTC', 'Bitcoin'], languages = ['en'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 445, in filter
    self._start(async)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 361, in _start
    self._run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 294, in _run
    raise exception
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 263, in _run
    self._read_loop(resp)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 313, in _read_loop
    line = buf.read_line().strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

pip3 shows tweepy

```
Name: tweepy
Version: 3.5.0
Summary: Twitter library for python
Home-page: http://github.com/tweepy/tweepy
Author: Joshua Roesslein
Author-email: tweepy@googlegroups.com
License: MIT
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

Comment: Seems that in this thread, https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/576 a solution has been found... Check the YukiDayDreamer's post. Let me know

Answer (score 0):

This should now be fixed in Tweepy v3.7.0 and newer.

See:
https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/576
https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/698
https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/commit/c1eddf1a5788ec4947d3a363dfe165ea599c31fc
https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1026
https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/pull/1027